# Killing black dogs

Tags: hadith, fiqh, sunnah, animals, dogs

Assalamun Alaikum,

A few weeks ago, I saw a Muslim woman on the news who had brutally killed an innocent dog. And she explained to the camera saying what she did was not against Islam and it was completely halal, she even said killing black dogs is sunnah and it is rewarded! I couldn't believe what I heard, so I searched it a bit.

Indeed, I found some hadith which Prophet Muhammad ordered all dogs to be killed, and then he abrogeted it and he ordered only black dogs to be killed. I thought it is haram to kill any innocent animal, whether it is black or white... Is it really a sunnah to slaughter black harmless dogs just because their fur is black, as that woman on the news said? I'd appreciate if anyone clarifies this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wa alaikum as salaam,

It is only permitted to kill a dog (regardless of their colour) if it's a rabid dog, a harmless dog must not be killed

Imam al-Haramayn stated that the command to kill dogs was abrogated. It was related that the Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) ordered the killing of dogs. Then, that was abrogated, except for pure black dogs. And thereafter, killing any harmless dog was prohibited. Thus, it is only permissible to kill a dog that may cause harm, like one with rabies. (Sharh Sahih Muslim v. 3, p. 536 and v. 10, p. 1931)

And Allah knows best